# Can SonarQube notification email quantity be reduced via batching?

Tags: email, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

We've been doing a bunch of bulk fixing of issues in our codebase (deprecated code usage, mostly) and every time the analysis kicks off next, everyone gets 10-100-1000 individual emails detailing the status changes that occurred.

Is there any way to consolidate all this information into a single email so users don't end up being unable to tell what's going on due to sheer bulk of repetitive information?

I really don't want to have to turn off the notification emails and implement my own email mechanism if I've just missed a setting or plugin somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the user notification subscriptions. Here are the different notifications a SonarQube can set in 6.7:

- Background tasks in failure on my administered projects
- Changes in issues assigned to me
- New quality gate status
- Issues resolved as false positive or won't fix
- New issues
- My new issues

Either keep only “My new issues” or unassign issues that will not be fixed by the author.

There's an [issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5210) that is linked to the problem raised. Feel free to vote for it.